# Installing VMWare Tools fails on fedora14 with " initctl: Job failed to start"

Tags: virtual-machine

I managed to install VMware Tools in Fedora 14.0  on VMware Workstation 15.0.1 like some installation guides suggesting:

```
mkdir /mnt/cdrom
mount /dev/cdrom /mnt/cdrom
cd /tmp
cp /mnt/cdrom/VMwareTools-x.x.x-yyyy.tar.gz  /tmp
tar zxpf /mnt/cdrom/VMwareTools-x.x.x-yyyy.tar.gz
umount /dev/cdrom 
cd vmware-tools-distrib
./vmware-install.pl
```

but it failed and I got the the following output:

```
Creating a new initrd boot image for the kernel.
Generating the key and certificate files.
Successfully generated the key and certificate files.
initctl: Job failed to start
Unable to start services for VMware Tools

Execution aborted .
```

I had installed kernel,kernel-devel,gcc,perl,fuse-libs and nmap before installing VMware Tools.
Also,I uninstalled vmware-tools with `vmware-uninstall-tools.pl` and installed it again,but it did not work.

Some advice said that just removing `/etc/init/vmware-tools-thinprint.conf` and then running the following:

```
/etc/vmware-tools/services.sh start
```

But I did not find the `vmware-tools-thinprint.conf` in my virtual machine。

As I run the `/etc/vmware-tools/services.sh start`,I got the following:

```
Checking acpi hot plug                                   [  0K  ]
Starting VMware Tools services in the virtual machine :
Switching to guest configuration:                        [  0K  ]
VMware Automatic Kmods :                                 [  0K  ]
Guest vmxnet fast network device:                        [  0K  ]
VM communication interface:                              [  0K  ]
VM communication interface socket family:                [  0K  ]
Guest filesystem driver:                                 [  0K  ]
Mounting HGFS shares:                                    [FAILED]
Blocking file system: .                                  [  OK  ]
Guest operating system daemon:                           [  0K  ]
VGAuthService:                                           [FAILED]
```

I'm a newbie and hope someone can help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The kernel of your Fedora guest is too old. The support for Fedora 14 ended long time ago. Is there any specific reason you are using it?

Maybe you should try the new release 29 with kernel 4.19. It should Work out of the Box. Also, I recommend using the open-vm-tools package from official Repo, since VMware open sourced it.

Regards

Comment: Thank you for your valuable advice. I  installed it successfully on another system. But the experiment I'm going to do requires a fedora 14 system, and I want to  solve this installation failure. Thank you again for your help